# Filter For Dates Outputted From Remote Logs Using Powershell

Tags: powershell, remote-server

Please see my current code bellow, the code will continue to keep running until stopped by user. The end goal is having the script to run and find a certain day and successfully stop or find results between 2 dates.

I have tried using -before -after flags with combinations of (get-date). IE .date .datetime .addday(+/-1) but when using them it finds the correct date and stops but takes 2/3 minutes before starting the script again or moving to the next machine in the list. I have also tried { $_.TimeGenerated -lt "00/00/000" }

Any idea's how this can be done? I've tried a few other things but having no joy.

```
$ComputerName = 'CSV File'
$UserProperty = @{n="User";e={(New-Object System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier $_.ReplacementStrings[1]).Translate([System.Security.Principal.NTAccount])}}
$TypeProperty = @{n="Action";e={if($_.EventID -eq 7001) {"Logon"} else {"Logoff"}}}
$TimeProperty = @{n="Time";e={$_.TimeGenerated}}
$MachineNameProperty = @{n="MachineName";e={$_.MachineName}}

foreach ($computer in $ComputerName) {
Get-EventLog System -Source Microsoft-Windows-Winlogon -ComputerName $computer | select $UserProperty,$TypeProperty,$TimeProperty ,$MachineNameProperty 
}
```

Comment: Well, I feel like this isn't really an accurate representation of your code. For instance, right now your foreach loop would run one time and would try to get the event logs from a computer named 'CSV File'. I don't think that will work. Maybe this link will help: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I will also point out as a general statement that getting remote event logs is typically pretty slow unless conditions are ideal (fast processor, fast I/O, small log files)

Comment: 'CSV File' was an example of the file instead of showing the path the actual file with name. The For Loop works prefect as it runs the command for every computer in the csv. All im looking to do is declare a date to search for.

Comment: This code you've pasted will grab all eventlogs for a machine, then if it's an event `7001`, list it as Logon, anything else (ANY OTHER EVENT) will be listed as Logoff.  If you want to gather all logon events, add that to `Get-EventLog -InstanceID 7001`.  When I run your code, all kinds of events are misclassified as Logoff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not positive exactly what issue you are having but this worked fine for me:

```
Get-EventLog System -Source Microsoft-Windows-Winlogon -ComputerName $computer -before '2017-11-09' -after '2017-10-27' -InstanceId @(7001, 7002) | select $UserProperty,$TypeProperty,$TimeProperty ,$MachineNameProperty
```

As I stated in the comment, getting remote event logs is generally a pretty slow process.

Here is a little timing info:

First I ran the request againsta server with no time filter at all:

```
measure-Command -Expression {$noTimeFilter = Get-EventLog System -Source Microsoft-Windows-Winlogon -ComputerName $computer -InstanceId @(7001, 7002)}
```

This took 292.85 seconds and returned 79 events. Next I ran it against the same server filtering for just the last 24 hours:

```
measure-Command -Expression {$withTimeFilter = Get-EventLog System -Source Microsoft-Windows-Winlogon -ComputerName $computer -after (Get-Date).AddDays(-1) -InstanceId @(7001, 7002)}
```

This took 243 seconds and returned 2 events.

So for this admittedly limited test filtering was actually faster. In my granted anecdotal experience filtering doesn't really make much difference one way or the other. I'm pretty sure the query gets all the events then filters them. If you are actually consistently seeing a faster return without a filter you could certainly just get everything every time then pipe that to a Where-Object block to get just the events that you wanted. This would be contrary to my experience though and as FoxDeploy pointed out potentially detrimental to the performance of your remote machines.

Comment: Specifically, gathering all event logs with no filter on remote PCs, this can be exceedingly slow (and crush the CPUs!) in a domain.

Comment: I updated the answer to filter for 7001 and 7002 events as per FoxDeploy's excellent comment.

Comment: When running the code above without -before -after the code executes really quick without any issue, it only begins to run slow when applying the search/filter. How would I run the code for current day

Comment: To save my time I had been testing these commands against a VM with very small log files. Give me a little time and I will provide some timing results against a server with substantially larger log files. I think you are probably getting in the weeds here. It is just an inherently slow process. If you can hget snappy results without the -before and -after parameters then get them and post filter with a Where-Object block.

Comment: Appreciate the help. Do you mean the command where-object e.g | Where-Object {$_.TimeGenerated -lt "17/12/2017"} or post my results on stack over flow

Comment: using the code that you modified for me I have roughly 22 servers in the list and the first 4 have roughly 12 users on them. filtering the server logs fininsh's in about 30 seconds at the very most. it brings back all instances of log in and out for the day as well as 4 events for the previous day event when its specified not to. the lengthy period is where the script stops and moves onto the next server in the list it takes about 3 minutes

Comment: Ultimately, all that matters is how long does it take from the time that it completes one server to the time it completes the next server. You can also use Measure-Command to verify the time that the command actually runs. I'm not sure exactly what else you want at this point.